# React: how to pass instance to onClick without using an active index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a list of elements in React that all call the same function attached to an `onClick`, let's say the function appends a class, how can I pass that instance to the function without it effecting ALL of the list elements.

Each time I click on a list element, all of my list elements are being effected.

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({ 
    expandedList: !this.state.expandedList
  });
}

render() {
 const folderStatus = this.state.expandedList ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'; 

 return (
  <div className="container">
    <ul>
      {folders.map((folder, index) => (
      <div onClick={() => this.handleClick()} 
           className= {folderStatus} 
           key= {index} >{folder}</div>
      ))}
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing the list index in your state might do the trick:

```
handleClick = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        // Make sure you collapse when you click twice on the same row
        selectedListIndex: prevState.selectedListIndex === index ? 'unclick' : index
    }));
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <ul>
        {folders.map((folder, index) => (
            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} 
                // Conditionally render the desired class
                className= {this.state.selectedListIndex === index ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'} 
                key= {index} >{folder}</div>
        ))}
        </ul>
```

Comment: dont you think this will run just on rendering?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick(index) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
        // Make sure you collapse when you click twice on the same row
        selectedListIndex: prevState.selectedListIndex === index ? 'unclick' : index
    }));
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <ul>
        {folders.map((folder, index) => (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,index)} 
                // Conditionally render the desired class
                className= {this.state.selectedListIndex === index ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'} 
                key= {index} >{folder}</div>
        ))}
        </ul>
```

Just minor change in Felipa's answer. `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,index)}`

If I want to use `this` inside function we have to bind `this` also

Comment: doesn't `onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}` cover it with the fat arrow?

Comment: OP wasn't binding on his example, so I assumed it was done in the constructor.

Comment: so if I bind it in constructor we can pass parameter as you have done @Felipe Lanza ?

Comment: If it's bound, you can call it that way. I've edited my post to make handleClick an arrow function as well.